# Finding the index of a number in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, sorting, indexing

So what im trying to do if find the index of a number in a specific row. I found the min, all i need to do is find the index of the number in a specific row.

i passed the values `3` and the array `cityDis` to `closestCity(int, int [][])` method.

i got that the minimum value in row 3 is 80 (disregarding 0). now all i need is a way to find the index of 80 in row `3`

is there even a way to do this?

```
int [][] cityDis = { {0, 10, 50, 100,}, {10, 0, 20, 80}, {50, 20, 0, 90,}, {100, 80, 90, 0} };

public int closestCity(int city, int arr [][])
{
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for ( int j = 0; j < arr[city].length; j++ )    //finds the min (disregarding 0)
            if ( (arr[city][j] < min) && (arr[city][j] != 0) )
                min = arr[city][j];
        for ( int j = 0; j < arr[city].length; j++ )
            if ( arr[city][j] = min )
                //this is where i get confused. I just want to find the index for just one row.
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index is your array params so, city and j are your indexes

Okay so you could do something like the following:

```
if(arr[city][j] == min) 
    int rowindex = j;
    int colindex = city;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return j;
```

in place of your comment. That should do it.

The value of "j" *is* the index that you are looking for! When you return at that point, you are done!